# error with an alias in .zshrc file

Tags: shell, zsh

I have a problem with en alias in my `.zshrc` file in `macOS`.
Here is the alias :

```
alias update='sudo softwareupdate -i -a; brew update; for i in $(brew cask outdated --quiet); do brew cask reinstall $i; done; brew cleanup -r; gem update --system; gem update; upgrade_oh_my_zsh; npm update -g; for x in $(pip3 list -o --format=columns | sed -n '3,$p' | cut -d' ' -f1); do pip3 install $x --upgrade; done';
```

When i call it, the shell answers me :

`-for cmdsubst>`

I can not find the origin of the problem.

Comment: Why would you use an alias for this? A function will avoid all the problems.

Answer (score 1):

The crux of the issue looks to be that you're using single quotes to define the alias, but you're also trying to use single quotes within it. This breaks the continuous string zsh needs to see when you define `alias foo=string`. You can use a single quote within a single quoted string by ending it, escaping the quote, and starting anew. For example:

```
alias foo='command '\''$1'\'' another-arg'
```

Or to include a quote at the end, just end the quoted string and escape just a single quote:

```
echo 'this is a single quote: '\'
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, if I put double quotes at the beginning and at the end of my alias, would that normally solve the problem ?

>alias update="sudo softwareupdate -i -a; brew update; for i in $(brew cask outdated --quiet); do brew cask reinstall $i; done; brew cleanup -r; gem update --system; gem update; upgrade_oh_my_zsh; npm update -g;for x in $(pip3 list -o --format=columns | sed -n '3,$p' | cut -d' ' -f1); do pip3 install $x --upgrade; done"

Comment: Yeah, it's ok. I've understood.

>alias update='sudo softwareupdate -i -a; brew update; for i in $(brew cask outdated --quiet); do brew cask reinstall $i; done; brew cleanup -r; gem update --system; gem update; upgrade_oh_my_zsh; npm update -g;for x in $(pip3 list -o --format=columns | sed -n '\''3,$p'\'' | cut -d'\'' '\'' -f1); do pip3 install $x --upgrade; done'

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Like [piojo wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45267196/2992551) the issue is that it is not possible to use single quotes within single quotes.

In this case, instead of working around the quoting, I would recommend to create a *function* instead of an *alias*.

```
update () {
    sudo softwareupdate -i -a
    brew update
    for i in $(brew cask outdated --quiet); do 
        brew cask reinstall $i
    done
    brew cleanup -r
    gem update --system
    gem update
    upgrade_oh_my_zsh
    npm update -g
    for x in $(pip3 list -o --format=columns | 
               sed -n '3,$p' | cut -d' ' -f1); do
        pip3 install $x --upgrade
    done
}
```

That way you need only the quotes you would need on the command line anyway. I think it also improves readability and makes edits easier. (Granted, it is also possible to have multi-line alias definitions)

Comment: I *would* point one towards [Don't Read Lines With `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Granted, zsh eliminates some of the bad decisions enshrined in POSIX, but habits folks learn in zsh tend to make their way elsewhere.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, good point. Although it should not be an issue here: Each returned line only contains a single package name, the package names are highly unlikely to contain any characters that may cause issues (white spaces, globs, etc.) and we are not interested in preserving possible empty lines.  Also, I only converted the given alias without any modification to the called commands.

Comment: One of the advisers relate to aliases is that if the code does not fit in one line it probably should be a function, or at least if it has so many pipes make it a function.